# Staff user is getting by default all permission in Django Admin Site - Custom User Model (AbstractBaseUser)

Tags: python, django

I am using Django custom user model inheriting from AbstractBaseUser & PermissionsMixin.

When I make a staff user, the user gets all the permission by default, means staff has superuser privileges of 'view', 'change', 'add', & 'delete' on all the apps and models in django admin site, But when I use Django's built-in User model it works perfectly fine, when a staff user login it says 'you don't have permission' and when I assign the permission I want to give the staff has the only permission in django admin site.

Do I need to update something which is commonly made mistake?

I tried changing has_perm and has_module_perms to return False but it restrict superuser also.

models.py:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
# Auth Details
...

# Profile Details
...

# Company Details
...

# Slug Field
...

# Required Fields
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

# Permissions Fields
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(_("Staff Status"), default=False, help_text=_("Designates whether the user can log into this admin site."))
is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_reseller = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_superreseller = models.BooleanField(default=False)

# App Permissions
...

# Reseller End User Mapper
reseller = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='belongs_to')

# Wallet Balance
wallet_balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3, default=Decimal('0.000'))

objects = AccountManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

def __str__(self):
    return self.username

def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    "Does the user have a specific permission?"
    # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
    return True

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
    # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
    return True

def to_json(self):
    return {
        'id': self.id,
        'username': self.username,
        'email': self.email,
        'phone_number': self.phone_number,
    }

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = slugify(self.username)
    self.wallet_balance = Decimal(self.wallet_balance).quantize(Decimal('.000'))  # Set precision to 3 decimal places
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

admin.py:

```
@admin.register(Account)
class AccountAdmin(ImportExportActionModelAdmin, UserAdmin):

list_display = ('id','username', 'wallet_balance','last_login','date_joined','is_active','is_reseller','is_superreseller', 'instant_demo_perm','reseller_username')
list_display_links = ('username',)
readonly_fields = ('last_login', 'date_joined')
search_fields = ('username', 'email')
ordering = ('-date_joined',)

filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions')
list_filter = ('is_active','is_reseller')
fieldsets = (
    (None, {'fields': ('username','email','password', 'reseller', 'wallet_balance')}),
    ('Personal Info', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'company_name', 'gst_number', 'address', 'city', 'state','country', 'pincode')}),
    ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_reseller', 'is_superreseller', 'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
    ('WhtsApp Permissions', {'fields': ('instant_demo_perm',)}),
    ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
)
add_fieldsets = (
    (None, {'fields': ('username','email','password', 'reseller')}),
    ('Personal Info', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'company_name', 'gst_number', 'address', 'city', 'state','country', 'pincode')}),
    ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_reseller', 'is_superreseller','groups', 'user_permissions')}),
)

def reseller_username(self, obj):
    return obj.reseller.username if obj.reseller else None
reseller_username.short_description = 'Reseller Username'
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply removed both the below methods and updated the qs on the required app admin.py file and it is now working as need.

staff user can login to admin site and only see the model objects which superuser assign them with respective permission.

```
def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    "Does the user have a specific permission?"
    # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
    return True

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
    # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
    return True
```

qs in admin.py of my app for which I want to give permission.

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super().get_queryset(request)
    qs = qs.annotate(numbers_count=Count('numbers'))
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return qs
    elif request.user.is_reseller:
        return qs.filter(
            Q(user=request.user) |
            Q(user__reseller=request.user) |
            Q(user__reseller__reseller=request.user)
        )
    else:
        # For other types of users (e.g., staff), return an empty queryset
        return qs.none()
```